# mounting galaxy s4 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, android, udev

The problem is as simple as the title, I can't mount my rooted galaxy s4 phone(newest update 4.4.2) on my laptop(running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). The error message is a consistent:

```
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:002,008]'
```

with the numbers changing depending on how many times I try and which usb port I use.

Let me be clear of my precautions. I have USB debugging mode set to off, and stay awake mode on(so that phone screen doesn't lock).

#### Here's what I have tried:

I have installed the `mtp-tools` here and from others.

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9
```

I have edited the `/etc/fuse.conf` file to not include the last comment.

```
#Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options.
>> user_allow_other
```

I have edited the `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` to include my phone with vendorID and productID

```
# Galaxy S4
ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

and I have edited the `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE=”0666"
```

I have installed `gvfs`.

Nothing has worked. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Will run any command and post outputs if needed.

Comment: Did you install the mtpfs package?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the mtpfs package.

Comment: It is starting to recognize it on and off now. Could very well be a usb cable problem. Will try some others to confirm. Sometimes it recognizes it and I can open and manage, sometimes it recognizes it then completely loses it, sometimes never mounts.

Comment: I've found that for some reason it works fine if I have the phone connected when rebooting.

Comment: What appears in `dmesg` after you plug the phone? Also under USB connection settings you may be able to use PTP instead of MTP, which might work

Answer (score 1):

found answer on [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/53250) by user [@Rat2000](https://askubuntu.com/users/79423/rat2000) on [AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com):

> Open a terminal in Ubuntu(Ctrl+Alt+T) and type this commands:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Then, launch Software Updater (previously known as Update Manager) and
>   install the available updates. After you update everything restart pc.
>
> if you want to revert back before making any changes:
>
> ```
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
> ```

Comment: For `Then, launch Software Updater (previously known as Update Manager) and install the available updates.` it may be simpler to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to need some setting on the phone to be enabled, these can be hard to find. A post on the [ASUS forum](https://www.asus.com/UK/support/FAQ/1015987) describes enabling developer options with USB debugging and then a menu should appear on storage setting page. This did not work for me but installing [USB Driver ForAndroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adbdriver.app&hl=en) allowed MTP and PTP options to be enabled.

Once installed gmtp started working fine.